# How to summon the wordpress post title into the article?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-shortcode

I'm having a problem where I want to add the title on my WordPress into an article so I can add a few keywords in it to automatically place the title without rewriting it. Does anyone know how?
The example is in the picture, but he uses blogger and I use WordPress with the classic editor plugin

I just want to know the code to summon wordpress title into an article automatically

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automatically insert the WordPress post title into your article content, you can use a shortcode

```
function insert_post_title_shortcode() {
  return get_the_title();
}
add_shortcode('post_title', 'insert_post_title_shortcode');
```

Comment: Hi, Heidar Ammarloo!

You posted 9 answers in June that appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT), with *five* of these having comments that said that the answer didn't work. Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.